# Python - how can I get the class name from within a class method - using @classmethod

Tags: python, class-method

I have the following code:

```
class ObjectOne(object):
    @classmethod
    def print_class_name(cls):
        print cls.__class__.__name__

    def print_class_name_again(self):
        print self.__class__.__name__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj_one = ObjectOne()
    obj_one.print_class_name()
    obj_one.print_class_name_again()
```

The output is:

```
type
ObjectOne
```

I would like the output to be:

```
ObjectOne
ObjectOne
```

But I would like to keep `test_cls` as a class method via the `@classmethod` decorator.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 55):

A classmethod receives the class as its argument.  That's why you're calling it `cls`.  Just do `cls.__name__`.

Answer (score 17):

It's `cls.__name__`. `cls` already points to the class, and now you're getting the name of *its* class (which is always `type`).

Comment: `s/always/usually/`. Metaclasses rock.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar question and wantend to get the class name for logging and the function/method name.

```
__name__ :  gives the program name
__class__.__name__ gives the class name
```

inspect.stack()[0][3] gives the module name. (you have to import inspect).

Cheers