# __PRETTY_FUNCTION equivalent in Python

Tags: python-3.x

g++ has this nice variable **PRETTY_FUNCTION** that contains the name of the function called. For functions it produces the prototype (e.g., "**void foo(long)**"). For member functions in classes, the name includes the class name (e.g., "**void Foo::foo(long)**").

Is there an equivalent in Python. I have been playing around with "**sys._getframe()**" which gets close, but there doesn't seem to be a similarly simple mechanism that includes the class name when it is a member function.

I like to use this in error handlers.

Surely someone has a magical one-liner for this...

TIA,

-Joe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback)

Comment: Plus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094961/python-how-can-i-get-the-class-name-from-within-a-class-method-using-classm for the class name.

Comment: I have looked at most of these examples. There are two issues: having it work transparently for class methods and functions (the C++ version does this) and wrapping the function to something user friendly like a variable definition ("__NAME__").

Obviously I can get a this information many ways and write some complicated function, but I was hoping there was something simpler. It seems like such a basic capability.

Answer (score 0):

[Example Python Code](https://www.isip.piconepress.com/tmp/python/code.py)

This is about the closest I can get right now. Search for "<<< here".

Typing Foo.**CLNAME** is kind of silly. It would be nice if this could somehow be collapsed to an external function and stay outside of the class. There must be a way to do this in Python in a way similar to the way **LINE** and **NAME** work.

The implementations of those two are based on code I got from here:

[How to determine file, function and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810999/how-to-determine-file-function-and-line-number/44248070)

Nice stuff!

-Joe

=====

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# import system modules
#
import os
import sys

# define a hack to get the function name
#                                                                             
class __MYNAME__(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        try:
            raise Exception
    except:
        return str(sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back.f_code.co_name)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

__NAME__ = __MYNAME__()

# define a hack to get the line number in a program                            
#                                                                             
class __MYLINE__(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        try:
            raise Exception
        except:
            return str(sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back.f_lineno)

__LINE__ = __MYLINE__()

# use these in a function call
#
def joe():
    print("[FUNCTION] name: %s, line: %s" %
          (__NAME__, __LINE__))                      # <<< here

# use these in a class member function
#
class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__CLNAME__ = self.__class__.__name__

    def joe(self):
        print("[CLASS] name: %s::%s, line: %s" %
              (Foo.__CLNAME__, __NAME__, __LINE__))  # <<< here

#--------------------------------
# test all this in a main program
#--------------------------------
def main(argv):

    # main program
    #
    print("[MAIN PROGRAM] name: %s, line: %s" %
          (__NAME__, __LINE__))                      # <<< here

    # function call
    #
    joe()

    # class member function
    #
    foo = Foo()
    foo.joe()

    # exit gracefully
    #
    sys.exit(os.EX_OK)

#
# end of main

# begin gracefully
#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[0:])

#
# end of file
```